# Java boolean[] to byte[] and back

Tags: java, boolean, byte, arrays

I am sending `byte[]` arrays over a socket connection in Java.

I have a pretty long `boolean[]` array, where `array.length % 8 == 0`.

I'd like to convert this `boolean[]` array into a `byte[]` array with 8 times as few elements, so that I can then send the `byte[]` over the socket connection.

The `boolean[]` array looks like this: `01011010 10101010 01100011 11001010` etc.

The `byte[]` in this case should look like this: `0x5A 0xAA 0x63 0xCA`.

I have found some code on another question on how to convert a single `byte` into a `boolean[]` array and added a new method to it to convert an entire array here:

```
public static boolean[] booleanArrayFromByteArray(byte[] x) {
    boolean[] y = new boolean[x.length * 8];
    int position = 0;
    for(byte z : x) {
        boolean[] temp = booleanArrayFromByte(z);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, y, position, 8);
        position += 8;
    }
    return y;
}

public static boolean[] booleanArrayFromByte(byte x) {
    boolean bs[] = new boolean[4];
    bs[0] = ((x & 0x01) != 0);
    bs[1] = ((x & 0x02) != 0);
    bs[2] = ((x & 0x04) != 0);
    bs[3] = ((x & 0x08) != 0);
    return bs;
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Edit: Thanks

Comment: The reverse is just… well, the reverse. You allocate an array of `x.length / 8` bytes, and fill them appropriately using a `for` loop and `|=`.

Comment: Why does your `booleanArrayFromByte(byte)` only return 4 bits?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Good point. I forgot to change it

Comment: Please check my answer, more short and efficient solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it something like this.

```
public byte[] toBytes(boolean[] input) {
    byte[] toReturn = new byte[input.length / 8];
    for (int entry = 0; entry < toReturn.length; entry++) {
        for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
            if (input[entry * 8 + bit]) {
                toReturn[entry] |= (128 >> bit);
            }
        }
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

This relies on the fact that `toReturn` will be initialised with all zeroes.  Then for each `true` that we encounter in `input`, we set the appropriate bit within the appropriate entry in `toReturn`.

Answer (score 6):

There already exists a class ([BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)) in the standard library to help you do this, you should use that instead of a boolean array. The class allows you to get and set bits and to various logical operations on your boolean values as a group.

eg.

```
BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(bytes); 
boolean third_bit = bits.get(3);
bits.set(5, false);
byte[] new_bytes = bits.toByteArray();
```

If you really need to use a boolean array then the following will work.

```
static boolean[] toBooleanArray(byte[] bytes) {
    BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(bytes);
    boolean[] bools = new boolean[bytes.length * 8];
    for (int i = bits.nextSetBit(0); i != -1; i = bits.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
        bools[i] = true;
    }
    return bools;
}

static byte[] toByteArray(boolean[] bools) {
    BitSet bits = new BitSet(bools.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < bools.length; i++) {
        if (bools[i]) {
            bits.set(i);
        }
    }

    byte[] bytes = bits.toByteArray();
    if (bytes.length * 8 >= bools.length) {
        return bytes;
    } else {
        return Arrays.copyOf(bytes, bools.length / 8 + (bools.length % 8 == 0 ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: This will ignore all false booleans. Ie: An array of booleans that are all false, will get an empty byte array.

Comment: Hmm, yes, this will ignore all higher zero bits after the last one bit. Not much effort to create a full sized empty byte array and copy over the bits byte array though.

Comment: With Java 8, in the "toBooleanArray(...)" method, you could replace the "for" loop with "bits.stream().forEach(bit -> bools[bit] = true);". It's a bit more succinct for the same work. (Not a really big deal, though.)

Answer (score 2):

For converting bytes to booleans:

```
public static boolean [] bytesToBooleans(byte [] bytes){
    boolean [] bools = new boolean[bytes.length * 8];
    byte [] pos = new byte[]{(byte)0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x8, 0x4, 0x2, 0x1};

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
        for(int j = i * 8, k = 0; k < 8; j++, k++){
            bools[j] = (bytes[i] & pos[k]) != 0;
        }
    }

    return bools;
}
```

Or another method:

```
public static boolean [] bytesToBooleansAnotherWay(byte [] bytes){
    boolean [] bools = new boolean[bytes.length * 8];

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
        int j = i * 8;
        bools[j] = (bytes[i] & 0x80) != 0;
        bools[j + 1] = (bytes[i] & 0x40) != 0;
        bools[j + 2] = (bytes[i] & 0x20) != 0;
        bools[j + 3] = (bytes[i] & 0x10) != 0;
        bools[j + 4] = (bytes[i] & 0x8) != 0;
        bools[j + 5] = (bytes[i] & 0x4) != 0;
        bools[j + 6] = (bytes[i] & 0x2) != 0;
        bools[j + 7] = (bytes[i] & 0x1) != 0;
    }

    return bools;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting from bytes to booleans:

```
private static boolean[] convertToBooleanArray(byte[] bytes) {
    boolean [] result = new boolean[bytes.length * 8];

    for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
        int index = i*8;
        result[index+0] = (bytes[i] & 0x80) != 0;
        result[index+1] = (bytes[i] & 0x40) != 0;
        result[index+2] = (bytes[i] & 0x20) != 0;
        result[index+3] = (bytes[i] & 0x10) != 0;
        result[index+4] = (bytes[i] & 0x8) != 0;
        result[index+5] = (bytes[i] & 0x4) != 0;
        result[index+6] = (bytes[i] & 0x2) != 0;
        result[index+7] = (bytes[i] & 0x1) != 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Converting from booleans to bytes by cutting off the last few booleans:

```
/**
 * This will round down to the nearest number of bytes.  So it will chop off the last few booleans.
 * Eg: If there are 9 booleans, then that will be 1 byte, and it will lose the last boolean.
 */
private static byte[] convertToByteArray(boolean[] booleans) {
    byte[] result = new byte[booleans.length/8];

    for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        int index = i*8;
        byte b = (byte)(
                (booleans[index+0] ? 1<<7 : 0) +
                (booleans[index+1] ? 1<<6 : 0) +
                (booleans[index+2] ? 1<<5 : 0) + 
                (booleans[index+3] ? 1<<4 : 0) +
                (booleans[index+4] ? 1<<3 : 0) +
                (booleans[index+5] ? 1<<2 : 0) + 
                (booleans[index+6] ? 1<<1 : 0) +
                (booleans[index+7] ? 1 : 0));
        result[i] = b;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Converting from booleans to bytes by padding the last few booleans:

```
/**
 * This will pad to the nearest number of bytes.  So the last few booleans will be set to the padValue.
 * Eg: If there are 9 booleans, then the last 7 will be added as the padValue (making 16 booleans).
 * 
 * @param booleans
 * @param padValue
 * @return
 */
public static byte[] convertToByteArray(boolean[] booleans, boolean padValue) {
    boolean[] paddedBooleans;
    int remainder = booleans.length % 8;

    // Booleans are already divisible by 8, nothing to pad
    if (remainder == 0) {
        paddedBooleans = booleans;
    }
    // Boolean are not divisible by 8, need to pad
    else {
        int padAmount = 8 - remainder;
        paddedBooleans = Arrays.copyOf(booleans, booleans.length + padAmount);

        for (int i=booleans.length; i<paddedBooleans.length; i++) {
            paddedBooleans[i] = padValue;
        }
    }

    // Convert the boolean array into a byte array
    byte[] result = new byte[paddedBooleans.length/8];

    for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        int index = i*8;
        byte b = (byte)(
                (paddedBooleans[index+0] ? 1<<7 : 0) +
                (paddedBooleans[index+1] ? 1<<6 : 0) +
                (paddedBooleans[index+2] ? 1<<5 : 0) + 
                (paddedBooleans[index+3] ? 1<<4 : 0) +
                (paddedBooleans[index+4] ? 1<<3 : 0) +
                (paddedBooleans[index+5] ? 1<<2 : 0) + 
                (paddedBooleans[index+6] ? 1<<1 : 0) +
                (paddedBooleans[index+7] ? 1 : 0));
        result[i] = b;
    }

    return result;
}
```