# Can you recommend any solution to save memory and load quickly in android?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have very big boolean array data.

How can i save memory and load this data quickly in android?

Comment: Sure you can use realm(realm provide speed what you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

150 items of boolean are small amount of data for conventional mobile devices. You can save more than 1000 items at once within 1 second.

**Method 1**

[Realm already supports](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types) `byte[]` as a datatype. You can use it by converting boolean array into byte array.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944410/361100

**Method 2**

As you know, `boolean` is just 1-bit(binary) data. There's lots of case to handle such bits, but for me, I love to handle it in naive manner.

1. Let say you have 160 items of boolean.

   - `true`, `false`, ..., `true`, `false`
   - It can be converted to `1` or `0`: `1010101....1010110`
2. 1 hex string contains 4 bits.

   - `1010 1110 0110 1100` can be expressed into `AE6C`
3. Likewise, `160` bits can be converted into `160/4=40` strings.
4. Just save 40 length strings to Realm or `SharedPreference`.
5. Want to load? no problem. Convert 40 length strings into 160 length boolean array.

I think it could consume less than 100ms as those converting process is pretty fast in modern mobile CPUs.

Comment: I prefer the `byte[]` solution, and it's really smart.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 4 possible soluzions: 

1.) You can serialize an Object and save it to a file.

2.) You can use Gson library and convert the object to JSON and save it to a file or in preferences.

3.) You can use Realm library which is fast. They even claim that on some operations they are faster than SQLite.

For solution 1 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896724/1502079

For solution 2 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16436363/1502079

Comment: there are like 300 more solutions

Comment: I think he needs a simple solution because he doesn't have much experience.

Comment: It depends on the amount of data you want to save. It takes less than a second if you don't have much data.

Comment: I used Realm in my projects and it's very fast and simple to use. But if you want a more specific solution then tell us some more details about your needs.